# Using laser_assembler in a separate node

Tags: ros, laser-assembler

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to give a try, if it works using [laser_assembler](http://ros.org/wiki/laser_assembler) for my purpose of building a point cloud. I'm somehow curios, is it possible(or better), to use the code snippet found in section 5.4 using a single separate node, instead of embedding it in my point cloud building specific node.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/13000/using-laser_assembler-in-a-separate-node/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I personally do the assembly of my Point Clouds in a separate node. I do this so that you abstract the assembly from your code. This increases re-usability of code and makes the code more generic for future uses. It is also good programming practice to create sub-systems within code that each perform a function without affecting other sections of code. This makes the code cleaner, simpler, and easier to maintain.

Additionally, if you generate the assembled cloud in a different node, you can write your point cloud processing node as a filter plugin to the [laser filter chain](http://ros.org/wiki/laser_filters) provided by ROS (which also works on Point Clouds).

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1